# I am not able to understand "aria-hidden" attribute in HTML

Tags: html

When I was doing website practice I found 'aria-hidden' attribute in <div> tag which I am not able to understand. I am also not able to understand the values given to this attribute like "true" and many more.
As I have written this <div aria-hidden="true"></div>

Answer (score -1):

The aria-hidden attribute is used in HTML to specify whether an element and its descendants should be exposed to accessibility tools, such as screen readers, or if they should be hidden from these assistive technologies.

When you set aria-hidden="true" on an element like , you're indicating that the content within that  and the  itself should be hidden from screen readers. This means that the content inside that particular  won’t be announced to users relying on screen readers or other assistive technologies.

This attribute is particularly useful when you have elements on your webpage that are used for visual purposes only (like decorative images or UI elements) and don’t carry any meaningful information for someone using assistive technology. By setting aria-hidden="true", you can improve the accessibility of your website by ensuring that such elements are ignored by screen readers, reducing confusion and providing a smoother experience for users who rely on these tools.

For example:

```
<div aria-hidden="true">
    This content is hidden from screen readers.
    <img src="decorative-image.jpg" alt="Decorative Image">
</div>
```

If aria-hidden is set to "false" or if the attribute isn't included, the element and its content will be accessible to screen readers, allowing them to announce the content to users who rely on these tools for navigation and understanding of the webpage.

```
<div aria-hidden="false">
    This content is accessible to screen readers.
    <p>Some meaningful text.</p>
</div>
```

Always use aria-hidden thoughtfully and ensure that hiding content doesn’t compromise the accessibility or usability of your website for users who rely on assistive technologies.

Comment: Please don't use text generated by AI as answers